# Responsive CSS form fields

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS to display my html form and labels for the fields:

```
#enquiryForm                    { clear:both; padding:8px 40px 0 0;  }
.enquiryField                   { clear:both; padding:5px 0; }
.enquiryField label             { clear:none; float:left; }
.enquiryField input             { clear:none; font-family:Calibri; float:right; padding:3px; width:189px; }
.enquiryField textarea          { clear:none; float:right; font-family:Calibri; padding:5px; width:189px; }

.enquiryError                   { clear:both; color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
#enquirySent                    { color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
```

what would be the best thing to do to make the text display on top of the fields as i want to put this into my responsive CSS code

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by 'on top' you mean directly before and not overlaying the inputs, because that would be weird.
Wrap it in a `@media` query and remove all floats, set widths to 100% and add some margins. It will display in a linear way across browsers / devices with a viewport less than 480px wide, update widths etc as needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/w9k5u/